Gnu-Parallelization within a shell script
I am using GNU parallel to run 3 scripts simultaneously. This is my current shell script.
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --array=0-0
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=07:30:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL

module load julia

parallel -j $SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE << EOF
julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 0
julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 1
julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 2
EOF

However, this fails to run. I used bash -x jobs.sh, to get some more insight, but found nothing of note. At first I suspected that it may be from the $SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE argument rather than just using the integer 3. However swapping this does nothing.
Any suggestions?

for i in 0 1 2; do julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 "$i" & done; wait

@tripleee This also fails. Sadly this isn't producing an output for me to follows up with.

parallel -j $SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 {} ::: 0 1 2

This also fails. sadly I am getting no error message to work with.

Add output of julia main.jl $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID 0.025 0 to your question (no comment here).

it seems $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is set someplace outside of the code you have included. You said you used bash -x job.sh, do you see the value for $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID included in your command? If yes, the it seems there is something else, first candidate is your use of julia which we don't know what is inside you main.jl.  Fall back to getting one instance of your juila cmd-line to work, using hard-coded values, no variables, and see what that uncovers. Good luck.

Have a look How I use bash or posix shell for draw a Mandelbrot by parallelizing works on many bc process here: Is bash a programming language? Note; I don't use parellel for parallelizing jobs under shell more sample at end of this.

@shellter You are correct. I did some digging and it seams that $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is not defined at all and instead the 0.025 is being taken as the first argument rather than the second.

It appears that in the process of debugging, I removed SBATCH --array. Hence $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID was left blank. This is rather embarising and clearly a night of good sleep was needed.
I will not remove this post since there were good ideas in the comments.

Proper quoting around this argument would probably have helped. We obviously cannot know what the command-line arguments mean or what values are valid without access to your Julia code.
